# Does exporting a module and never importing it anywhere affect performance?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, import, export

I have a React/TS repository with about 600 exported modules, interfaces, functions, types(etc) which are not imported anywhere.

Aside from being bad practice, does this affect the app performance in ANY WAY?

I tried finding the answer online but there seems to be none.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I would expect that the resulting webpack output simply wouldn't include modules which aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is tree-shaking, which is supposed to eliminate unused code.
Take a look at https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/.

> The webpack 2 release came with built-in support for ES2015 modules (alias harmony modules) as well as unused module export detection. The new webpack 4 release expands on this capability with a way to provide hints to the compiler via the "sideEffects" package.json property to denote which files in your project are "pure" and therefore safe to prune if unused.